# Wayland/Ubuntu 22.04 mouse cursor icon not responding on some apps

Tags: mouse, icons, wayland, cursor

I am on ubuntu 22.04 with "Mesa Intel® Graphics (ADL GT2)" graphics.
Clicking and everything else works, only cursor icon is not appropriate for its position on screen.

Some apps show proper cursor icon (resize, text, hand, etc) like terminal and files.

Some apps show only default cursor icon like firefox and virtualbox.

Please help me solve this :)

Comment: You are using a different cursor theme than default? Problem the same on Xorg? I presume yes. It can depend on whether the app is installed trough snap, and it can also depend on the toolkit with which the app is build.

Comment: I'm using default cursor theme, In relation to theme I only changed settings in appearance settings
Xorg does not have these issues

Comment: It may help if you document your customizations in your question.

Comment: for me too. dconf-editor , then apply, icon shows correctly for firefox,terminal, pan, thunderbird   but not for kate(text editor/IDE) , krusader, konsole, . cursor is Yaru, default.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your issue, this is a known bug for firefox - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1774531

Not sure though since you're saying you're seeing this on multiple apps not just firefox.